# Switch TABS (not windows) in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, authentication

Is there a way for switching TABS (not windows) in python selenium?
I explain: I need to perform a google login in capital.com, so the script clicks on "login", then select "login with google" and then a new tab will open where i have to choose the account, now, I can't interact with the google login tab because the focus of selenium is on the "mother tab".
How I can do this and then go back to the first tab?
(Shortcut commands SHIFT+TAB won't work)

```
def login():
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#wg_loginBtn")))
    login = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#wg_loginBtn")
    login.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#l_overlay > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(2)")))
    google_login = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#l_overlay > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(2)")
    google_login.click()
    #This is where I need to switch
    account_login = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.JDAKTe:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2)")
    account_login.click()
```

Comment: windowhandles is what you need. Could you show your code?

Comment: I tried capital.com, but are there any regional restrictions on this website? I see that I cannot click on Login with Google (it's disabled), and then Login with Facebook and Login with Apple opens in entirely new windows (not tabs)

Comment: Edited with code, anyway the login with google is equal with other sites. (sorry for bad english) PS. Maybe the new tab is just for firefox??

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:
I used window handles since even in firefox I get it in a new window and not a tab. But even if it is a tab instead of a window, this should work. Try this out.

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.capital.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='wphWrap']//a")))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='wphWrap']//a").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Continue with Google']").click()
time.sleep(1)
winhan = driver.window_handles
print(winhan)
print(winhan[1])
driver.switch_to.window(winhan[1])
time.sleep(1)
print(driver.current_url)
print(driver.title)
email = driver.find_element(By.ID, "identifierId")
email.send_keys("abc@gmail.com")
print(email.get_attribute('value'))
driver.switch_to.default_content()   # switches back to parent window
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
['38cb2fdd-b4a7-41d1-bee9-113b6766e0d4', '998cc211-d667-4a9b-927c-c829e98e295e']
998cc211-d667-4a9b-927c-c829e98e295e
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=storagerelay%3A%2F%2Fhttps%2Fcapital.com%3Fid%3Dauth584347&response_type=permission%20id_token&scope=email%20profile%20openid&openid.realm=&include_granted_scopes=true&client_id=454579592242-gnbnhkk834jh482n40b71q2nm0hfrvjj.apps.googleusercontent.com&ss_domain=https%3A%2F%2Fcapital.com&prompt=select_account&fetch_basic_profile=true&gsiwebsdk=2
Sign in – Google accounts
abc@gmail.com

Process finished with exit code 0
```

You may replace time.sleep with webdriverwait conditions.